# Selenium under Windows 7 cannot start FirefoxDriver: Can't load profile

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I see a lot of similar questions as old as mammoth crap, which minds Firefox 22 or something like that. I faced the same issue:
`Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: c:\users\alp\appdata\local\temp\tmprcb81b`

Unittest starts firefox, creates profile directory in %temp% succesfully, but after timeout fails with specified error message. I am using latest Firefox (45.0b with multiprocessing) and Python 2.7.11

What have I tried:

- I tried to downgrade to version 40.0 (single processing) and delete my profile direcrtory. It does not works.
- I tried to upgrade Selenium to latest version (`pip install -U selemiun`). Pip upgrades from 2.5.0 to 2.5.1 without any affects.
- I added log file to FirefoxBinary and it does not contains even `WARN` sign. Accordingly to log it looks like Firefox starting right and stops without any reasons.
- I tried to delete entire repository, get new one and re-run unit test.
- Finally I created virtual machine with Python 2.7.11, git, Firefox 40.0 cloned repo and started test again. With not luck.

I am completely mad about it amd have no any ideas how to fix this issue. Do you have any?

Comment: To me it looks like a permissions issue, never had it tho.
As it makes things easier for me I'm running the selenium server from Cygwin and the profile gets created in (file:///C:/cygwin/tmp/anonymous3765949956426318133webdriver-profile/)

Comment: Perhaps it is this bug: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1300 That was the issue for me on a slower computer (Raspberry Pi). Firefox couldn't start up before the hardcoded 30 second timer killed it.

Comment: @Alex unfortunately no. I think that Lenovo E440 is fast enough for firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still not found solution **at this moment**, but reasons is clear. For that moment Firefox >=44 under Windows 7 x64 does not support injected Selenium's addon. It could be easily checked - once Firefox started (and nevertheless is invisible for selenium's engine) type `about:addons` and check "Extenstions" tab. On older version addon "WebDriver for Firefox" just marked as "unsigned and potentially dangerous". On newer ones it is disabled.

My current workaround (I do not want to downgrade my primary browser) is to download FireFox Portable, put it somewhere and instantiate driver with binary:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile,    
    firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary(firefox_path=r'D:\path\to\old\crap\FireFox37\firefox.exe '))
```